# How to download a pdf file in angular which is generated on my server(springboot)?

Tags: angular, rest, spring-boot

"I want to download a .pdf file sent from spring-based restful web service to my angular app. How to download it, am I missing some code on my angular app or spring boot?"

I am sending an HTTP GET request from an angular 6 app to my spring-boot server, which generates a .pdf file and then sends me this .pdf file as a blob, 
but when I try to create a blob on my angular side and open the pdf, it shows the following error :

. ERROR Error: The request body isn't either a blob or an array buffer

I have visited the following questions on StackOverflow, to find some solution:
1. [PDF Blob is not showing content, Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046133/pdf-blob-is-not-showing-content-angular-2)
2. [How can I get access to the Angular 2 http response body without converting it to string or json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36087145/how-can-i-get-access-to-the-angular-2-http-response-body-without-converting-it-t)
3. [converting byte stream in HTTPResponse body into a pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51633734/converting-byte-stream-in-httpresponse-body-into-a-pdf-file)
4. [Send File with SpringBoot to Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51417520/send-file-with-springboot-to-angular2)

**In Angular app:**
*component:*

```
getPDF(){
      this.apiService.getPDF(this.invoiceId)
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          //data.blob() doesnt work properly
          var file = new Blob([data.blob()], { type: 'application/pdf' })
          var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
          window.open(fileURL); // if you want to open it in new tab
          var a         = document.createElement('a');
          a.href        = fileURL; 
          a.target      = '_blank';
          a.download    = 'bill.pdf';
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.click();
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log('getPDF error: ',error);
        }
      );
    }
```

*Service:*

```
    getPDF(invoiceId : number)
         {
             this.url = this.main_url + '/invoices/generatepdf/'+invoiceId;
             const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
             "Authorization": authorization, responseType : 'blob'});
             return this.http.get(this.url, { headers : headers})
                 .pipe(map(
                     (response) => {
                         return response;
                     },
                     (error) => {
                         console.log(error.json());
                     }
                 ));
         }
```

**In Spring boot:**

*Controller:*

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/invoices")
    public class InvoiceController {

    @Autowired
        InvoiceService invoiceService;

    @GetMapping(path = "/generatepdf/{invoiceId}")
        public void generateInvoicePdf(@PathVariable Integer invoiceId,
                HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
            invoiceService.generateInvoicePdf(invoiceId, request, response);
    }
```

*ServiceImplementation:*

```
    @Override
        public String generateInvoicePdf(Integer invoiceId, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

             //createPDF() will create a .pdf file
            createPDF(pdfFilename, dto, dtoForSupplier);
            if (pdfFilename != null) {
                try {
                    File file = new File(pdfFilename);
                    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
                    response.setContentType("application/blob");

                    // Response header
                    response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
                    response.setHeader("responseType", "blob");
                    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + pdfFilename + "\"");

                    // Read from the file and write into the response
                    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
                    System.out.println(os);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) file.length()];

                    int len;
                    while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        os.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    }

                    System.out.println(os);
                    os.flush();
                    os.close();
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return pdfFilename;
        }
```

I expect to download a .pdf file in the browser and open it and see its contents, but instead i get the error:

> core.js:15724 ERROR Error: The request body isn't either a blob or an array buffer
>       at Response.push../node_modules/@angular/http/fesm5/http.js.Body.blob (http.js:782)
>       at SafeSubscriber._next (invoice-details.component.ts:212)
>       at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:196)
>       at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:134)
>       at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:77)
>       at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
>       at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:41)
>       at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:1070)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)>

Comment: Can you be more specific to the problem you are having? I can't tell easily as to what the issue is (there's way too much code here to figure out what is wrong).

Comment: in the `ServiceImplementation ` change `response.setContentType("application/pdf")` or tell what is response do you get in angular?

Comment: @kgdesouz I just want to download a pdf file sent from spring-based restful web service to my angular 6 app,  Can you give me a small example of how it can be achieved?

Comment: Go to https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get. Click on "15 overloads...". Find the one that returns an Observable<Blob>. Hint: it's the second one. Look at what you must pass as options to use that overload (hint: it's not a header that you need to pass). Then note that it returns an Observable<Blob>. So what the observable emits **is** a Blob. Not an object with a blob() method property which would return a Blob.

Comment: @AlirezaKhajavi changed the code to response.setContentType("application/pdf") but still I get the same error saying 
**Error: The request body isn't either a blob or an array buffer**

Comment: Additional tips: Specify the return type of your service method, so that the compiler can check that the method indeed returns the correct type. Don't use `map(response => response)`, since that's completely useless and just clutters the code.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you very much. Finally figured it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As suggested by @JBNizet , I have implemented the observable as follows:

**Component:**

```
getPDF(){
      this.apiService.getPDF(this.invoiceId)
      .subscribe(
        (data: Blob) => {
          var file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' })
          var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

// if you want to open PDF in new tab
          window.open(fileURL); 
          var a         = document.createElement('a');
          a.href        = fileURL; 
          a.target      = '_blank';
          a.download    = 'bill.pdf';
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.click();
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log('getPDF error: ',error);
        }
      );
    }
```

**Service:**

```
getPDF(invoiceId : number): Observable<Blob>
     {
         this.url = this.main_url + '/invoices/generatepdf/'+invoiceId;
         var authorization = 'Bearer '+sessionStorage.getItem("access_token");

         const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         "Authorization": authorization, responseType : 'blob'});

         return this.httpClient.get<Blob>(this.url, { headers : headers,responseType : 
         'blob' as 'json'});
     }
```

**URL's that I referred:**

1. Overload #2: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get
2. Preview Blob with Http Post: 
   https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-preview-blobs-with-http-post-and-angular-5

Comment: the above one directly downloading , open PDF in new tab not working

Comment: This worked for me (both downloading and opening a new window). If you use typescript however you need to cast the result of document.createElement to <HTMLAnchorElement>